# What rendering API does Qt use on Windows?

Tags: windows, qt

What underlying rendering system does the Qt GUI toolkit use on Windows?  (I'm assuming it is GDI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QT is a c++ library, and preduce native application. so the only option is:

gdi/gdi+