# Which parts of Windows does Qt rely on?

Tags: qt, activex, qobject

I believe Qt uses GDI(+) and you start with a QObject. Does it call ActiveX components, COM etc?

For example, putting WebKit in a form is there anything happening there that uses the Windows bits and pieces for painting?

I'm just a beginner trying to work out how much of WINAPI, COM, and ActiveX is used/wrapped by Qt.

Comment: If anybody has a 'the this bones connected to that that bone' on what is between QT and GDI/forms in windows/etc it would be great.

Comment: I interpreted your question as a more general "What parts of Windows does Qt rely on?" However from that comment, I suspect you're asking [this exact question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1315880/594137).

Comment: I am not sure if it will be useful or add more confusion...

Answer (score 1):

In general Qt only implements a feature if there is a sensible(/compatible) metaphor for that feature on all* supported platforms. It makes use of a lot of different Microsoft and non-Microsoft components on Windows, not just the one's you have mentioned.

I've not found a document which summarises what you're asking before because it's not something I've ever needed or found useful as the document would be immense. The way I tend to work with Qt is read the excellent documentation and believe it until I find something which does what I didn't expect it to. Then delve into what it does under the bonnet(/hood) for that specific platform. Remember, the source code is freely available.

---

** Note: there are some features which are platform specific in the framework but these are usually clearly identified as such.*

Comment: Thanks Styne666.  So there's no obvious insight to what is under the hood?  Someone told me that webkit everything was practically an activeX (In there guess).  I hope there isn't that much double handling going on...

Comment: Well yes, there is: [the source](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt). There is always going to be a performance hit when abstracting an operating system. My advice would be to use Qt until you find a bottle neck, then profile and optimise. You can still compile in your own platform specific bits later on down the line if you find you need *actually* need them.

Comment: Looking thur a million lines of code is not obvious for a noob like me :P